# $max evaluation of a compound key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How does the Aggregation Framework's `$max` operator evaluate on a compound key. For example:

```
{
  $project: { 
    user: 1, 
    record: { date: "$upload_date", comment: 1, some_integer: 1 }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$user",
    latest: { $max : "$record" }
  }
}
```

Will it get the maximum by `date`, `comment`, or by `some_integer`? I just assumed it will get the latest by `date`. If it's wrong, what is the correct way of finding the maximum by `date`?

**Edit**

From what I have tried so far, the latest record is determined by the first key. Is this the correct behavior?

**Edit**

To give an idea of my use case, I have the following document:

```
  > db.logs.findOne()
  {
  'id': ObjectId("50ad8d451d41c8fc58000003")
  'name': 'Sample Log 1',
  'uploaded_at': ISODate("2013-03-14T01:00:00+01:00"),
  'case_id': '50ad8d451d41c8fc58000099',
  'result': 'passing'
  'tag': ['TAG-XYZ']
  }
```

And I have the following aggregation:

```
  db.test_case_logs.aggregate(
  {$project: {tag:'$tag', case:'$case_id',
    latest: {upload_date:1, date:'$upload_date', result:'$result',
    passing : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$result","passing"] }, 1, 0 ] },
    failing : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$result","failing"] }, 1, 0 ] }}
  }},
  {$unwind: '$tag'},
  {$group: {_id:{tag:'$tag',case:'$case'}, latest:{$max:'$latest'}}},
  {$group: {_id:'$_id.tag',total:{$sum:1}, passing:{$sum:{$latest.passing}},
    failing:{$sum:{$latest.failing}, date:{$max:{$latest.upload_date}}}
  },
  {'$sort': {'date':-1}}
  )
```

Logs can have the same name `tag` and `case_id` and after grouping twice, I need the result to be only the latest logs by `upload_date` for each `tag`.

**Edit**

My expected result is something like:

```
  {
    '_id':'TAG-XYZ',
    'total':'1'
    'passing':'1'
    'failing':'0'
  }
```

Each count corresponds to the latest log of a given case.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using ?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 2.2

Comment: In the updated aggregation operation, you [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/) the **tag** field, but the value of tag is not an array, this will generate an error. And could you give more information on the query and expected result? (e.g. the $sum operation)

Comment: @LindaQin, sorry that was a typo and I forgot to add some of the fields in the query as well. Please see the latest edit. Rest assured, that's my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`$max` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/max/), this operator

> Returns the highest value among all values of the field in all documents selected by this group.

You can specify the max operation on date by { $max : "$record.date" }

The aggregation operation is like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate ([
    { $project: { 
        user: 1, 
        record: { date: "$upload_date", comment: 1, some_integer: 1 }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$user",
        latest: { $max : "$record.date" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Yes, I think, it will get the latest `date`. But what if I want to preserve the contents of the `record` field? That is, I want to get the latest combination of `date`,`comment`, and `some_integer` with the maximum `date`?

Comment: @nyde1319: If you are just after the latest record based on date value (or some other criteria), you don't need to use the Aggregation Framework.  Just do a `db.collection.find().sort({'date':-1}).limit(1)`.

Comment: @Stennie: Please see the updated question for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can use the `$sort` operator to sort all the logs by $uploaded_at field, and  group the sorted results by tag and case_id, and then use the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/) operator to get the first item for each group.

```
db.logs.aggregate([

    // Rename the fields and process the result field
    { $project : {
          tag : 1,
          case : "$case_id",
          date : "$uploaded_at",
          result : {
              passing : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$result","passing"] }, 1, 0 ] },
              failing : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$result","failing"] }, 1, 0 ] }}
    }},

    // Create a stream of documents from the tag array 
    { $unwind : "$tag" },

    // Sort by uploaded date descending
    { $sort : { date : -1 }},

    // Group the documents by tag and case_id, and use $first operation to get the latest log for each group
    { $group : {
          _id : { tag : "$tag", case : "$case" },
          latest : { $first : "$result" },
    }},

    // Group the document by tag, and caculate the total/pass/fail results
    { $group : {
          _id : "$_id.tag",
          total : { $sum : 1 },
          passing : { $sum : "$latest.passing" },
          failing : { $sum : "$latest.failing" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: I suppose that will work, but I wonder what are the implications of my usage of the `$max` operator. Will the results be unpredictable?

Comment: @nyde1319 The $sort (descending on a specific field) and $first operations can help us to get the max result for this specific field.

Comment: With a large number of documents in my case, the problem I am seeing with the use of the `$sort` pipeline is that it may consume much memory as defined [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/#memory-for-cumulative-operators).